# nth-child CSS - matching 2nd, 5th, 8th, ... elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've got a HTML list which with the aid of CSS I'm arranging in blocks of rows of 3 columns.

So, if the list has 6 elements it would be 2 rows x 3 columns, 9 elements - 3 x 3, 12 elements - 4 x 3, etc, etc.

How do I using the CSS nth-child selector select the middle element of each row?  ie., the 2nd, 5th, 8th, ... elements.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This should work:

```
:nth-child(3n+2) {
    // your css rules here
}
```

Basically, the `3n` means "every third" while `+2` means "starting with number two".

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: Ha!  I was getting the figures the wrong way around!  You get the points as you were the quickest back.  Ta!

Answer (score 9):

```
li:nth-child(3n+2) {
    //whatever you have to do
}
```

See this as a reference https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

Answer (score 8):

If I understand your question correctly, `:nth-child(3n+2)` is what you want. (See e.g. [this JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/urdh/43yxZ/))