# Middle Child Pseudo-Class

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way to use CSS selectors to get the middle child in a list of elements?

I know that there is no literal `:middle-child` selector, but is there another way without resorting to Javascript?

Comment: Does the number of children change?

Comment: The number of elements is set at page load and may vary user to user.

Comment: If you're working in PHP or Ruby or whatever, you could certainly write a function to add a class to the middle element.

Comment: You're absolutely right, and that's what I'm already doing. I was mostly looking for some sort of CSS trick I wasn't aware of.

Comment: Such a pseudo-class wouldn't make sense, because what would be the middle child in an even number of elements? Your code may be able to guarantee an odd number of elements, but not every page can guarantee such a situation.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Javascript is the only way to do this client side.

Comment: There should be sass solution

Answer (score 34):

This has been working well for me:

```
*:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
    ...
}
```

You can see an example of this here: http://codepen.io/bentomas/pen/Gwqoe

The one caveat to this is that it only works in IE 9+: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3

Comment: Wouldn't that only work if there's three items? At the time I was looking for something with more elements than that in it.

Comment: Nope, this will select all elements that are not the first child and not the last child.  You can see it in action here: http://codepen.io/bentomas/pen/Gwqoe

Comment: Oh, unless you want the *exact* middle child (i.e. only one element should ever be matched).  I was thinking you wanted to select all the children that are in the middle.  At least that's what I expected a `:middle-child` pseudo class to do when I went looking for it and found this thread.

Comment: @bentomas - Well, you just solved my little problem in a very powerful way. So, thank you. =)

Comment: unfortunately it does select not only one middle element

Answer (score 13):

While not elegant, if you know the upper and lower limits of the total number of elements, you could take a brute force approach to select the middle element.

For example, the following rules will select the middle element in a set of 5, 7, or 9 elements.

```
div:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(3) {
  /* The middle element in a set of 5 is the 3rd element */
}

div:nth-child(4):nth-last-child(4) {
  /* The middle element in a set of 7 is the 4th element */
}

div:nth-child(5):nth-last-child(5) {
  /* The middle element in a set of 9 is the 5th element */
}
```

Or with Sass:

```
@for $i from 3 through 5 {
    div:nth-child(#{$i}):nth-last-child(#{$i}) {
        /* The middle element */
    }
}
```

Comment: If there can be an even number of elements, one might include `div:nth-child(-1+#{$i}):nth-last-child(#{$i})` and/or `div:nth-child(#{$i}):nth-last-child(-1+#{$i})` to select the element just left or right of center, respectively.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the "not first and not last" approach, like so:

**CSS**

```
li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
  color:red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

Check the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ronency/oop7v9aw/)

Comment: what if there is 5 items ?

Comment: @Mo. this will apply to all middle children. Go to the JsFiddle link provided, add a couple more <li> in the middle and re-run it. You'll see them all turn red!

Comment: OP: "the middle child" meaning one

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply a style to all elements that are neither first children nor last children, you could use `:not(:first-child)`, apply the style, and then use `:last-child` to 'take the style away' from the last element.  But you'd have to think about what happens when there are less than 3 elements.

Comment: If you want to avoid the duplication (of the 'take the style away' section), check my answer, that combines two 'not' selectors, in order to catch all of the middle elements... :-)

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the need to target the middle child on several occasions, and I've taken to using this sass mixin I wrote after referencing many similar questions, and their respective answers.

```
// Generate a reasonable number rules limited by $n.
@mixin middle-child($n) {
  // There is no middle for nChildren less than 3,
  // so lets just start at 3.
  @for $i from 3 to $n {
    // Find the middle, bias right for odd numbers.
    $mid: math.ceil(math.div($i, 2));
    // Select only those sets of children that number $i.
    &:first-child:nth-last-child(#{$i}) {
      // Select the middle child of that set.
      ~ :nth-child(#{$mid}) {
        @content; // Apply your styles.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
.navigation {
  background-color: #ba0020;

  .nav-item {
    color: white;
    
    @include middle-child( 8 ) {
      font-weight: 900;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `:nth-child(#)` ?

Depending on which one you want to select you just replace # with the number.

Comment: That only works if the number of elements is known to begin with. I'm looking for something that will work for a list of unknown length.

Comment: Well, I suppose if you don't know the total number this won't help either, but in case you DO - take a look at this [CSS3-nth-child on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692145/nth-child-css-matching-2nd-5th-8th-elements) it's a similar question to yours.