# Flexbox UL LI in two columns with fist column content align RIGHT and second column content align LEFT

Tags: css, flexbox, html-lists

I need help with flexbox `ul` and `li` columns and their content aligns. Actually, I would like to use column-count if it is possible to divide one UL into two columns. Flex-wrapper  which holds `ul` as container needs to center the whole UL list (content), but the first column and second column need to have opposite content alignment. I am stuck on another column. Any advice?

```
                          (flex-wrapper) align: center  



       text-align:right ( column 1 )    ( column 2 ) text-align: left
```

```html
<div class="flex-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>Fully air-conditioned</li>
    <li>Free private parking area</li>
    <li>Free outdoor shower</li>
    <li>Free barbecue on disposal</li>
    <li>Free Wi-Fi Internet</li>
    <li>Multilingual host</li>
    <li>Free local TV and SatTV stations</li>
    <li>Pets are not allowed</li>
    <li>Smoking allowed outdoor</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```css
.flex-wrapper {
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-image: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-wrapper ul li {
  text-align: right;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 4px 0 4px 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: **This is not possible**. CSS columns are *not elements* and so cannot be selected or styled with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flex-wrapper {
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-image: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-wrapper ul li {
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 4px 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.flex-wrapper ul li:nth-child(-n+4) {
  text-align: right;
}

.flex-wrapper-2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-image: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-wrapper-2 ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.flex-wrapper-2 ul li {
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 4px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.flex-wrapper-2 ul:nth-child(1) li {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<h1>Wrapper 1</h1>
<div class="flex-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>Fully air-conditioned</li>
    <li>Free private parking area</li>
    <li>Free outdoor shower</li>
    <li>Free barbecue on disposal</li>
    <li>Free Wi-Fi Internet</li>
    <li>Multilingual host</li>
    <li>Free local TV and SatTV stations</li>
    <li>Pets are not allowed</li>
    <li>Smoking allowed outdoor</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<h1>Wrapper 2</h2>
<div class="flex-wrapper-2">
  <ul>
    <li>Fully air-conditioned</li>
    <li>Free private parking area</li>
    <li>Free outdoor shower</li>
    <li>Free barbecue on disposal</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Free Wi-Fi Internet</li>
    <li>Multilingual host</li>
    <li>Free local TV and SatTV stations</li>
    <li>Pets are not allowed</li>
    <li>Smoking allowed outdoor</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Use CSS [:nth-child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) like thus:

```
.flex-wrapper ul li:nth-child(-n+4) {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: unfortunatelly this does not work because nth-child(1) up to nth-child(5) in my code are in first column. I would like solution where I can add more content in list via CMS editor and not to count them in css to apply alignment. What If I add more content in list, do I need to apply more css lines in code for each one?

Comment: @user2114900 I modified the example to apply the text-align to the first 4 list items :nth-child(-n+4). If you add things to the list you would need to remember to update the css also. If you want the list creation and styles to be calculated dynamically you need to implement the list element using JS.

Comment: I am agree with you but I does not satisfy my further needs because I will need it for dinamical content. Probably there is some css solution for it without JS but I can`t find it.

Comment: You could create two lists side-by-side and align one on left and one on right and handle your list items dynamically.

Comment: I know, I tried on several ways but also that it is not a sollution to fullify my needs. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Sure, I added an example where two ul-lists are side-by-side and not defined by the static CSS. So you just need to handle the list items correctly into each list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's currently possible to do exactly what your asking for using only CSS3 while still accounting for a dynamic list size.

The trouble is accessing column-count breakpoints in css. If you can find the middle element then you can use a sibling selector to change all subsequent items to 'align: left'. I couldn't find a way to do this, but it may warrant further investigation. Here's a starting point: [Middle Child Pseudo-Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267601/middle-child-pseudo-class)

If you can get the computed x-offset from the parent (aka `left: n`) after it calculates the column break then you can use attribute syntax to identify which elements are in the right column. Again, I couldn't find any documentation on how to do this.

I won't say it's impossible to do exactly what you want, but I wouldn't get your hopes up. However, if you are willing to drop the use of `column-count` and accept an alternating left > right > left > right order instead of left fill > right fill order, then it's totally doable.

here's the CSS:

```
.flex-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* or use align-items: center for a direction: column */
}
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
li {
    width: 50%;
}
li:nth-child(odd) {
    text-align: right;
}
```

While this method doesn't achieve the order you want, it does produce the style without the need to modify your html or add javascript. It also handles dynamic list sizes.

I'm actually really curious if someone can find a perfect solution for this.